# CRUD: Null record pattern

Tags: java, c#, sql, database, null

With simple CRUD UIs, we often face select/dropdown elements which may have a blank. These are most likely used to establish the relationship between an entity and a standard type (lookup value).

Would it be wise to avoid handling the exceptional `null` value case by having a record that represents a `null/none/not selected` assuming the distinction between "no association ever existed" and "currently no association" is unimportant in the domain?

At first glance it seems that this approach which is similar to the [Null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) could be helpful, but I may be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar design decision to make recently, but went with leaving nulls in database tables where the users didn't choose any lookup values. Main reason was that queries were a lot easier as we didn't need to re-establish concept of what is `NULL/NONE/NOT_SELECTED` in our UI/backend code or other queries. We also experimented with using Empty GUID's for `NULL` lookup values (000000-0000...), but in the end decided against it.

Answer (score 0):

Null is a very cool feature for data modeling if you have use for it, and extra effort if you use it when it's not necessary.

If a 'none' value should be treated differently then a 'not selected' value (that is, there is a significance for some decision that you are going to make), then use null as 'not selected' separately from 'none'.

If you are NOT going to treat 'none' and 'not selected' differently in your processing, then use a single value for both purposes.

Comment: Would you see any harm in using a "null record" as the unifying value?

Comment: I see no harm at all. (re-reading my answer, I see you could infer differently). Perhaps a simpler summary statement would be: "Don't use 2 different values, when a single value will serve the purpose."

Comment: I never intended to use more than a single value, but "use a single value" doesn't say anything regarding `NULL` vs null record association. That's the core of my question. The advantage I see using a null record is that the UI nor the backend update process have to account for a special-case blank option.